# Is it a goal if, during kicks from the penalty mark, the ball goes outside the penalty area and then into the goal?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

If, during kicks from the penalty mark, the ball hits the goalpost and lobs outside the penalty area and then returns back into the goal without touching any player, will it be considered a goal or not?

Please provide a reference to IFAB laws if possible.

Comment: I'm finding it *really* hard to imagine a situation in which this could possibly occur. Do you have an example of when this has actually happened, or is it purely a thought experiment?

Comment: @PhilipKendall, it's getting really difficult if the bal leaves the penalty area(for obvious reasons), but similar things have happened when the ball goes less far from goal.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fpydN6rejI, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ab3WF_e-J8M. There was also an almost instance of it on the last World Cup

Comment: @ThomasDB Do we know what the referee did in that instance? I don't see any reason it shouldn't be a goal, but I don't see the referee confirming it on the video.

Comment: It looks like it yes, the second vid is a bit longer and shows the other team celebrating after another penalty kick. Assuming the video is chronologically correct team A hits the crossbar, keeper from team B starts celebrating but ball goes in behind his back. After that player from team A asks ref if it counts, ref seems to confirm. Text says: "co(n)valida il gol", convalida is Italian for validate it seems.

Comment: If goalies can kick free kicks where it's so windy that the ball winds up back in their goal, I'd think the scenario is within the realm of possibility.  Really windy day, really hard kick, ball rebounds hard passing out of the box, but is blown back in as it bounces\rolls?

Answer (score 19):

On page 55 of the [2014/15 FIFA Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/27_06_2014_new--lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf), in the *Kicks from the Penalty Mark* procedure, it says

> Unless otherwise stated, the relevant Laws of the Game and International F.A. Board Decisions apply when kicks from the penalty mark are being taken.

This means that, since no other description is given, Law 14 (governing Penalty Kicks during the game) applies to this situation, with the exception of the placement of extra players.

On page 45, *Law 14 (The Penalty Kick)* says, in regard to a goal being scored:

> A goal is awarded if, before passing between the goalposts and under the crossbar the ball touches either or both of the goalposts and/or the crossbar and/or the goalkeeper.
>
> ...
>
> The referee decides when a penalty kick has been completed.

So, in the situation you describe the ball hits the goalpost/crossbar, hits the ground and then goes back into the goal. This would be a goal unless the referee had decided that the kick was completed. If the ball had landed all the way outside the penalty area (very unlikely), it's possible the referee would have blown the ball dead since it was so far from the goal. But if he hadn't, it's a goal.